# Swift Table View Cell layout collapses all elements

Tags: ios, swift

I'm fairly new to Swift and iOS programming, but I'm facing the following problem. I'm working on a TableViewController and on the first cell I started designing my layout. 
I Created a View that has 0 margin to all sides and 150 height, then I arranged all components inside a horizontal stack view inside and added constraints as I considered appropriate. On storyboard everything looks fine, but when I run the app on the emulator, all elements collapse and don't maintain their proportions. Here is a screenshot of the storyboard.

[image: ViewCell in Storyboard]

As far as I can see, the ContentView and the tableCell doesn't seem to have a way of setting constraints, I have tried setting a custom row height or specifying height and width of some elements but it still collapses. What could I be doing wrong?

Here is how it looks on the emulator:

[image: emulator screencaupture]

**EDIT ADD CODE**
Here is the code of the Table View Controller

```
class UserPostsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(RegisterPost(_:)))

        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150.0

        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        let sv = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: self.view)

        let userName = userPreferences.object(forKey: "sessionEmail") as! String

        apiClient.GetPostsByUser(userName : userName) { response in
            self.posts = response
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            UIViewController.removeSpinner(spinner: sv)
        }
    }

    let apiClient = ApiClient()

    let userPreferences = UserDefaults.standard

    var posts = [Post]()

    @objc func RegisterPost(_ sender : UIButton){
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registroPostSegue", sender: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return posts.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! PostCellTableViewCell

        let post = posts[indexPath.row]

        cell.postLabel.text = post.nombre
        cell.categoryLabel.text = post.categoria
        cell.postImageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: post.imagen!))

        cell.postIsOpen(isOpen: post.abierto)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return 150.0
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2** Capture of element distribution on this controller

[image]

Comment: Haven't you set tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self. delegate properties. also check your Content View Contraints are correct.

Answer (score 0):

try using the following delegate method in the code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return 150.0
}
```

EDIT:
In swift:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
     heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
 return 150.0
}
```

Comment: Implemented this override, but this still doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't added these it :

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding.

Comment: This is setting row height correctly, but my views still collapse :(

Answer (score 0):

if your all constraints seems to be fine. Please use below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

if you done above, still you don't get proper result. Please check your constraint inside of UITableViewCell.

Comment: This code should go on the TableViewController or the TableViewCellController ? and which constraint do you refer? Where is that option?

Comment: it should go in tableviewcontroller or viewcontroller. By the way if you have used stack view, it will automatically set views inside it. only you need to added its top, leading, trailing and bottom constraints. Also you can take stackview inside of stack view to manage controls.

Comment: Still haven't got this working, I'm adding my view controller code

Comment: Please return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in heightForRow. And please check your layout in preview. And check your logs if you get any constraint breaking messages displays.

Comment: No error displays on this view, I still don't find what is my issue on the storyboard

Comment: just try putting only two lables one on top and one on right bottom..and check is that work. And first remove all your controls.